# Independence of increments of some processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am stuck on this question:

Let $(B_t)$ be a standard Brownian motion. Define
$$ (\tau_1)_t := \inf \{s \geq 0 : B_s = t \} ; \quad  (\tau_2)_t := \inf \{s \geq 0 : B_s > t \}. $$

Any ideas how to prove that $(\tau_2)_t$ has independent increments? Also, I am not sure whether $(\tau_1)_t$ has independent increments.

Comment: Sure about this? For every $t\geqslant0$, $(\tau_1)_t=(\tau_2)_t$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did I am actually not sure about $\tau_1$, but I know that $\tau_2$ definitely has independent increments, but do not know how to prove.

Comment: @Did I edited the question for this.

Comment: Not that the edit makes a difference, one still has $P((\tau_1)_t=(\tau_2)_t)=1$ (can you show this?).

Comment: Yes, it follows by Strong Markov property to show that $(\tau_2)_t \leq (\tau_1)_t$ a.s.. The converse follows by continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Note that both processes are non-decreasing. Can be shown that $\tau_2$ is cadlag (right continuous, with left limits) while the $\tau_1$ is the opposite.

Moreover, $\tau_2$ is Levy process, more specifically Lévy subordinator.

For more details consider the book
“David Applebaum - Levy processes and stochastic calculus”,
Theorem 2.2.9