# Hitting Times for Brownian Motion - Levy Process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, levy-processes

Let $X$ be a Brownian motion and let
$$H_a = \inf\{ s \ge 0 \mid X_s = a \} \;\ \text{and} \;\ S_a = \inf\{ s \ge 0 \mid X_s > a \}.$$

Now, I've shown that $H_a$ and $S_a$ are equal almost surely (pretty straightforward). Importantly (I'm assuming), I've shown that $H = (H_a)_{a\ge0}$ and $S = (S_a)_{a\ge0}$ are not almost surely equal (in fact, I'm pretty sure that I could extend this to 'almost surely not equal').

I want to show that $S$ is a Levy process but that $H$. I think I have a proof for $S$.

> $$S_b - S_a = \inf\{s \ge 0 \mid X_s > b\} - \inf\{s \ge 0 \mid X_s > b\}$$
>   $$ = \inf\{s \ge S_a \mid X_s > b\} \sim \inf\{s \ge 0 \mid X_s > b-a\} = S_{b-a}$$
>   by the strong Markov property (of $X$). So we have stationary increments. Further, the strong Markov property again says that we have independence of the past.

Note that $X_{S_a} = a = X_{H_a}$. Unfortunately, I don't see why this doesn't apply in exactly the same way with $S$ replaced by $H$! Any advice would be most appreciated!

---

Note that there are also these two SE questions.

- [Continuous in probability of hitting times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086106/continuous-in-probability-of-hitting-times)
- [Independence of increments of some processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086043/independence-of-increments-of-some-processes?lq=1)

Unfortunately, they don't clarify it for me either! Indeed, in the one with the answer, the answerer appears to strongly imply that $H$ *is* a Levy process. My question is taken from a past exam paper, so I'm guessing that it's right (not always the case though!).

---

Here's the exact question.

[image: Question]

I've actually thought of a better argument than I gave for the second part of (b). There's no non-trivial interval on which BM is non-decreasing. In particular, on any non-trivial interval it must attain a maximum (which is finite almost surely). Let this be attained at $a$. Then $H_a < S_a$.

Comment: I am afraid that when you write $X_{S_a} = a = X_{H_a}$ this is wrong. Take for example a Poisson Process started at 0. Then $S_0=0$ and $H_0 =\tau$ where $\tau$ is the first time $X$ jumps, then $X_{S_0}=0\not=X_{H_0}=1$. Best regards

Comment: Don't understand your claim that $H = (H_a)_{a\ge0}$ and $S = (S_a)_{a\ge0}$ are not almost surely equal. Do you assume the Brownian motion $X$ has continuous sample path? If so,  $H$ and $S$ are the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate your point? Thanks.

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks for your comment, but if you check the first line, you'll see that $X$ is a Brownian motion. I agree with your example regarding a Poisson process, but that isn't continuous, whereas Brownian paths are (almost surely).

Comment: @Jay.H I'll add some more details to the end.

Comment: @ Smiley Sam : I read only the title about Lévy process.

Comment: @SmileySam: Concerning point b): Does your definition of "Levy process" require a process that is right continuous with left limits? (I ask this because $H$ does have stationary independent increments.)

Comment: Assertion d) is false. The process $S$ is right continuous with left limits, and has (almost surely) countable many jumps. But $a\mapsto S_a$ is continuous for all $a$ outside that countable set of jump times.

Comment: Ah, of course, a Levy process is cadlag! How silly of me to forget that! My stationary and independent increment argument works for both $S$ and $H$ yeah? It's at the jumps that $H$ is left continuous with right limits (cf $1(Y \ge 0)$) and $S$ is right continuous with left limits (cf $1(Y > 0$))?

Comment: Pretty awful that the question is wrong. I mean, a typo is one thing; but I agree with you that (d) is just plain false. This is Part III Advanced Probability from 2010 for goodness sake! (That is, unless we're both wrong!)

Comment: Also, $S$ is non-decreasing certainly, so if it were nowhere continuous, it couldn't be everywhere finite (almost surely)? (I'm not 100% on this, but I can't think of how it could be: it would have to have uncountably many jumps and so equal $+\infty$ everywhere almost surely?)

Comment: Sorry, swap my "cf"s around; hm, going to have to think about that now. Sorry, can you explain why $S$ is cadlag but $H$ isn't? I seem to be getting it the other way around!

Comment: For (d), perhaps the author meant to say: the set of discontinuous points are dense, a.e.

Comment: Maybe. I can't think of a proof immediately, but I can see why the set would be dense. Still, not great. =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was incorrect. See comments for a (short) discussion and suggestion of what it should be. This answer is being posted merely so that the question is removed from the unanswered pile. (Answer written by OP)